# Call and SMS permission is not given but still getting warning from google play

Tags: android, android-permissions

**Google Console**

[image]

**Android Manifest File**

[image]

[image]
I have not used any of the call and sms permission but still i'm getting the warning message from google play..what would be the solution? Please suggest me!

Comment: try my this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54749187/4696610

Answer (score 0):

As you've now posted your gradle file, it turns out the [PayUMoney Android SDK](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App) is the culprit.

Other people have [raised the issue on their GitHub repo](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK/issues/43), you need to [submit a permissions declaration form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/viewform) to Google Play, explaining that you need the permissions to perform SMS verification.

Specifically, this exception from [Google's help article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303):

> SMS-based financial transactions (e.g. 5 digit messages), and related activity including OTP account verification for financial transactions and fraud detection

Comment: thanks @jakeSteam for your answer....but in my other application i have not used this GET_TASK permission but still i get that warning..what would be the reason?

Comment: I suggest you add this new information into your question, which currently has very little information in it! Please show your other app's manifest. It's possible a third party library you're using requires the permissions, so posting your `build.gradle`s would be helpful too.

Comment: @dannymorrison Please add this into your *question*, not comments! Then it can be formatted properly.

Comment: It can also be due to payumoney using the permission. try using the latest version of dependency.

Comment: @KaranMer can u please suggest the new version of payumoney?

Comment: you would need to refer the developers website, I am currently unable to access it.

Comment: @dannymorrison Please see my updated answer. PayUMoney is absolutely the issue, I've linked you to others having an identical issue, and a potential fix.

Comment: No worries. Make sure mark your question as solved (tick next to this answer) if you're happy with the answer.

Comment: one final question....do i need to remove the payumoney integration or is there any updates in it to remove the sms permission?

Comment: @dannymorrison Well, if you fill in that form, and google agrees your app is exempt (which it seems to be, since it's listed as an excluded use case), you won't need to remove the permission. I suggest you fill it in ASAP!